# How to implement Sessions in a Facebook Multi-pages canvas application (php sdk 4.0)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-canvas, facebook-sdk-4.0

Here is my question:
Im trying to create a Facebook Canvas Application with PHP sdk 4.0 and im lost in all the confusing documentations...
I don't understand how the login process is working with multiple pages application. Can someone help me please?

I put this code on the landing page of the app and that works fine:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id', 'app_secret' );
$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {}
```

the question is: what should i do on the second page?
_Write the same code?
_Save the Facebook session in $_SESSION in order to use it on the other pages?
_Save only the token to retreive the session?

I walked the web for 2 days to find the answer with no result..
I found Facebook documentation is not very clear

Thx to you a lot!  ;)

Comment: why not go the easy road and use the JavaScript SDK? it´s so much easier, and the usability is much better. No page refresh needed when the token is not valid anymore, and no redirect needed for the login process. just a nice popup with FB.login. also, no PHP needed, which means no server with PHP5.4+. and you never need to save the token and stuff, because the SDK does everything for you.

Comment: thx for your answer. I'm going to look at this but the problem is the same: how do i implement sessionning? which function(s) should i call on each page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the session / access_token and save it to a PHP Session, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $session->getToken();
```

[This tutorial I wrote will help you out](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).